# JavaScript readAsDataurl is not a function

Tags: javascript, filereader

In Gecko/Firefox I got the error message:

> TypeError: fr.readAsDataurl is not a function

Using the following JavaScript:

```
var fr = new FileReader();
fr.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters I asked the question in the fashion others who will encounter it would ask and posted the answer in the fashion fitting to the situation. Are you suggesting that I post the answer inside of the question? That wouldn't make logical sense.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that you had created a self-answer here. My mistake!

Comment: Thanks . Ran into the same problem

Comment: @32teeths The best way to thank on Stack is up-voting questions and/or answers. I post in spite of the fact that people are in a rush to down-vote what I post to help people.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As it turns out someone at Mozilla created the deprecated method `readAsDataurl` with the improper letter casing and since JavaScript is case sensitive I simply had to use the `readAsDataURL` method (uppercase URL):

```
if (fr.readAsDataURL) {fr.readAsDataURL(files[i]);}
else if (fr.readAsDataurl) {fr.readAsDataurl(files[i]);}
```

Note that the standard/proper casing method is detected *first*. If you want your code to work as quickly as possible performance will improve over time as standards support improves.